# Hash Table that tries to hash Strings uniformly?

Tags: string, hash, hashtable, hash-collision

I am currently in a Data Structures course nearing the end of the semester, and have been assigned a project in which we are implementing a Linked Hash Table to store and retrieve keys. We have been given a pretty large amount of freedom with how we are going to design our hash table implementation, but for bonus points we were told to try and find a hash function that distributes our keys (unique strings) close to uniformly and randomly throughout the table.

I have chosen to use the ELF hash, seen here http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx

My question is as follows: With this hash function an integer is returned, but I am having trouble seeing how this can be used to help specify a specific index to put my key in in the hash table. I could simply do: index = ELFhash(String key) % tableSize, but does this defeat the purpose of using the ELF hash in the first place??

Also I have chosen my collision resolution strategy to be double hashing. Is there a good way to determine an appropriate secondary hashing function to find your jumps? My hash table is not going to be a constant size (sets of strings will be added and removed from the set of data I am hashing, and I will be rehashing them after each iteration of adding and removing to have a load factor of .75), so it is hard for me to just do something like k % n where n is a number that is relatively prime with my table size.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question, and let me know what you think!

Answer (score 1):

You're correct to think about "wrapping bias," but for most practical purposes, it's not going to be a problem.

If the hash table is of size N and the hash value is in the range [0..M), then let `k = floor(M/N)`.  Any hash value in the range `[0..k*N)` is a "good" one in that, using `mod N` as a map, each hash bucket is mapped by exactly `k` hash values.  The hash values in `[k*N..M)` are "bad" in that if you use them, the corresponding `M-K*n` lowest hash buckets map from one additional hash value. Even if the hash function is perfect, these buckets have a higher probability of receiving a given value.

The question, though, is "How much higher?" That depends on M and N. If the hash value is an `unsigned int` in `[0..2^32)`, and - having read Knuth and others - you decide to pick prime number of buckets around a thousand, say 1009, what happens?

```
floor(2^32 / 1009) = 4256657
```

The number of "bad" values is

```
2^32 - 4256657 * 1009 = 383
```

Consequently, all buckets are mapped from 4256657 "good" values, and 383 get one additional unwanted "bad" value for 4256658. Thus the "bias" for is 1/4,256,657.

It's very unlikely you'll find a hash function where a 1 in 4 million probability difference between buckets will be noticeable.

Now if you redo the calculation with a million buckets instead of a thousand, then things look a bit different. In that case if you're a bit OC, you might want to switch to a 64-bit hash.

On additional thing: The Elf hash is pretty unlikely to give absolutely terrible results, and it's quite fast, but there are much better hash functions. A reasonably well-regarded one you might want give a try is [Murmur 32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash). (The Wiki article mentions that the original alg has some weaknesses that can be exploited for DoS attacks, but for your application it will be fine.) I'm sure your prof doesn't want you to copy code, but the Wikipedia page has it complete. It would be interesting to implement Elf yourself and try it against Murmur to see how they compare.